# How to overwrite text in AngularJS using a filter

Tags: html, angularjs

Still learning Angular however I need a quick fix for something and I can't figure it out. I have a site that gives you the USPS shipping options and need to tell the website to use my text instead of the vendor's. The vendor's says '2-Day Ship™' but I want to replace that with just 'Standard Ground'.

This is what I have for my filter:

```
app.filter('shipFilter',function() {
return function(string) {
    if (string) {
        return string.replace('2-Day Ship™', 'Standard Ground');    
    }
}
```

And in my html:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-change="updateShipper()" name="shipMethod"
        ng-model="currentOrder.LineItems[0].ShipperName"
        ng-show="user.ShipMethod.ShipperSelectionType == 'UserDropDown'"
        ng-options="shipper.Name | shipFilter as (shipper.Name + ' ' + (shipper.ShippingRate.Price | currency | xlat)) for shipper in shippers"
        ng-required="!currentOrder.IsMultipleShip() && user.ShipMethod != null" />
<option value=""></option></select>
```

It seems like it would be an easy patch however I'm running into walls and out of time.

Cheers

Comment: Why don't you just change the name in `shippers` instead?

Comment: Because the vendor also returns a more expensive option, 'Next Day', so I need both to show up. The problem that arose is the '2 Day' option isn't necessarily 2 days so my customers are getting cranky. I'm frustrated because typically I can figure this stuff out, while I'm learning it, but have hit a roadblock. I think the ™ is screwing me up honestly.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. How would just changing the name straight in `shippers` effect any of the other options? Basically what I'm asking is instead of using the filter option to attempt to loop through and change the specific option why not just do it manually yourself?

Comment: The drop down shows 2 options for the customer: 2 Day (with a dollar amount based off weight) and a 2nd option of Next Day (with a dollar amount based off weight as well). If I just changed the name in the HTML wouldn't the drop down still show the other two options?My knowledge with web coding is from over 10 years ago so I'm just now getting back into it and getting up to speed so my apologies if I'm not explaining myself too well.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying. The actual shipper name is out of my control and the e-commerce site's. It's passed from USPS directly.

Comment: Seems like a lot of logic in the template...

Comment: Yeah. It's my client's e-commerce site and I'm basically cutting and pasting to do what my client wants it to do. My problem is my js knowledge is limited as it's been over 10 years since I worked with it in college. That's why I turned here. I'm learning the new stuff to help myself out, however I promised my client I'd have this little patch fixed by Monday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while but I wanted to post what I did to fix. I had to do this:

filter.js

```
//For changing USPS shipping option in dropdown
four51.app.filter('USPSFilter',function() {
debugger;
return function(object) {
    if (object) {
        return object.replace(/USPS Priority Mail 2-Day™/g, 'US Postal Ground');
    }
}
});
```

Added this to html to display change in dropdown:

```
ng-options="shipper.Name as ((shipper.Name | USPSFilter) + ' ' + (shipper.ShippingRate.Price | currency | xlat)) for shipper in shippers"
```

Added this to my controller.js:

```
$scope.items = [{name: 'Ground' },{ name: 'Rush' }]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm on the same page at @MatthewGreen here. You have an array in your scope, so you can just modify the array in scope. However if that absolutely isn't possible I wrote a snippet that correctly changes the string name.

```js
strs = [
  "2-Day Ship™",
  "Next Day"
]

var filter = function(string) {
    if (string) {
        return string.replace(/2-Day Ship™/g, 'Standard Ground');    
    }
}

console.log(strs)
strs = strs.map(filter)
console.log(strs)
```

Comment: Adrian, thanks for helping out. I haven't really worked with js for over 10 years and I vaguely recollect working with arrays however I believe, because the "2-Day Ship™" comes directly from USPS I'm not sure I can adjust the array. And if I can, I'm at a loss. 

As for the code you gave me, do I just inject that into my app.filter and replace what I already have? I don't mean to sound like I have no clue, but I really don't and that's why I turned to this crowd. Normally I can figure it out on my own, but not this time.

Comment: If you have an array, there is no reason you can't modify it. Worst case just make a copy. As for this code, yes you would just replace your existing filter.